# Converting a float to bytearray

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a float to a bytearray, but I keep on receiving both no input, and extreme slowing/freezing of my computer.

My code is

```
import struct

def float_to_hex(f):
    return hex(struct.unpack('<I', struct.pack('<f', f))[0])

value = 5.1  # example value
# ...
value = bytearray(int(float_to_hex(float(value)), 16)
```

I found on another article a function to convert floats to hex which is

```
def float_to_hex(f):
    return hex(struct.unpack('<I', struct.pack('<f', f))[0])
```

and then I converted it from hex to an int.

What is the problem with this? How could I better convert it from a float to bin or bytearray?

Comment: Why do you want a float as a bytearray?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is this to display the binary form of the float as hexadecimal text, or to get the raw bytes? Using `hex` implies you want hexadecimal text, not the raw bytes, and in that case, you wouldn't want a `bytearray` at all (which is a binary data type), you'd want `str` (the text type in Python 3).

Comment: Also, do you really want C `float` or C `double` representation?

Comment: What I am looking for is getting the raw bytes. I got the function while looking up a way to represent IEEE (754) floating point in hex from floats. I know it would be correct if I could plug the hex string into http://gregstoll.dyndns.org/~gregstoll/floattohex/ and get the original number.

Comment: @tatatat0: If you're entering this on a webpage, you don't want the raw bytes, you want the hex representation of said bytes; I can't reach that site (proxy blocking it), but web forms generally don't accept inputs of raw binary data, they take a hex encoded version. For the record, Python's `float` type is actually based on the C `double` type, not the C `float` type (which is typically half the precision of `double`), so you might want format code `d`, not `f`. As I mentioned in another comment, on 3.5, `struct.pack("f", value).hex()` should get you the hexadecimal text you want.

Comment: For example, `struct.pack("<f", 5.1).hex()` returns `'3333a340'`; does that work for your purposes?

Comment: What are you going to do with the "raw bytes" once you have them?

Comment: @cdarke: for machine learning, I'd like to represent text by turning  a string into an array, each element representing a number corresponding to a character. bytearrays help with that.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It depends what you want, and what you are going to do with it.  If all you want is a bytearray then:

```
import struct

value = 5.1

ba = bytearray(struct.pack("f", value))
```

Where `ba` is a bytearray.  However, if you wish to display the hex values (which I suspect), then:

```
print([ "0x%02x" % b for b in ba ])
```

This gives (for value 5.1):

```
['0x33', '0x33', '0xa3', '0x40']
```

However, CPython uses the C type `double` to store even small floats (there are good reasons for that), so:

```
value = 5.1
ba = bytearray(struct.pack("d", value))   
print([ "0x%02x" % b for b in ba ])
```

Gives:

```
['0x66', '0x66', '0x66', '0x66', '0x66', '0x66', '0x14', '0x40']
```

Comment: Slightly nicer/faster way to format the hex (dropping `0x` and leaving it as a single hex string) would be either `struct.pack("f", value).hex()` (requires 3.5+ but produces `str` for output directly) or `binascii.hexlify(struct.pack("f", value))` (works on any Python version, but returns `bytes` object; would need to decode as `ascii` to get `str`, e.g. `binascii.hexlify(struct.pack("f", value)).decode('ascii')`). But if the goal is just a `bytearray`, unformatted, then yeah, what you've got is the obvious way.

Comment: @ShadowRanger:  good suggestions, I tried to keep it simple because I find the requirement vague.

Comment: note: `binascii.hexlify()` works on `bytearray()` too.

Comment: The result I would want from 5.1 is 0x40 a3 33 33 or 64 163 51 51. Not as a string. I would only ever want to see the string for debugging. Your first answer seems correct. Why is it that the solution I initially had was so intensive and gave no return?

Comment: That's the problem when you heavily nest function calls as you do - they are a pig to debug.  The intensively is because the number you are putting into `bytearray()` is huge: 1084437299 in the example of 5.1.  You are not converting that number to bytes, you are creating a byte array **of that size** :  "*If it is an integer, the array will have that size and will be initialized with null bytes.*"  https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray

Comment: Further to my previous comment, the following correction to your code appears to work:  `value = bytearray(float_to_hex(float(value).encode())`

Comment: The `"d"` format character should be right atop the answer, not hiding in edit :)

Answer (score 7):

> The result I would want from 5.1 is 0x40 a3 33 33 or 64 163 51 51. Not as a string.

To get the desired list of integers from the float:

```
>>> import struct
>>> list(struct.pack("!f", 5.1))
[64, 163, 51, 51]
```

Or the same as a `bytearray` type:

```
>>> bytearray(struct.pack("!f", 5.1))
bytearray(b'@\xa333')
```

Note: the bytestring (`bytes` type) contains exactly the same bytes:

```
>>> struct.pack("!f", 5.1)
b'@\xa333'
>>> for byte in struct.pack("!f", 5.1):
...    print(byte)
...
64
163
51
51
```

The difference is only in mutability. `list`, `bytearray` are mutable sequences while `bytes` type represents an immutable sequence of  bytes. Otherwise, `bytes` and `bytearray` types have a very similar API.