# Convert List of Floating point to bytearray and back in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, floating-point

I am trying to convert a list of floating point number to bytearray and convert it back to original list. My list looks like this: 
[-0.055999, -0.054000, -0.049, -0.040999, -0.037000]

I am trying to use bytearray(list) but only accepts integers.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're trying to do this? To (not really) answer your question, you can't do what you're trying to do. The allowed inputs of `bytearray` can be seen here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray

As you can see, an iterable of floats (and floats more generally) is not valid inputs.

Comment: Maybe this could help you. [Converting a float to bytearray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36894176/8743158)