# Converting list of numbers to binary file

Tags: python, list

I have a very long list of large numbers in Python in the form

`[429996711.2753906, 106845465.30664062, 47285925.673828125, 373352395.4082031, 934463030.1191406, 53994183.962890625, 455503649.6542969, 741004174.1660156, 725379998.9648438, 485329924.8046875, 16476769.255859375,...]`

for example.  I need to convert each number from decimal to binary, and then save these binary numbers into a raw binary file without CRLF line-endings.  Would anyone be able to say how to do this? I haven't been able to find a usable answer anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to take a look at the struct package: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet creates a file `data.bin` with 88 bytes (11 doubles of 8 bytes each):

```
import struct

data = [429996711.2753906, 106845465.30664062,
    47285925.673828125, 373352395.4082031,
    934463030.1191406, 53994183.962890625,
    455503649.6542969, 741004174.1660156,
    725379998.9648438, 485329924.8046875,
    16476769.255859375]

packed = map(lambda i: struct.pack("@d", i), data)

with open("data.bin", "wb") as fh:
    for i in packed:
        fh.write(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert your decimals to a bytearray or similar - see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36893206/10993299) on converting floats to bytearray
2. Write the bytearray to a file in binary mode - use the "wb" mode in an `open()` function to mark the file as binary, as discussed in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367007/python-how-to-write-to-a-binary-file) on how to write a bytearray of ints to a binary file.

```py
# make file
newFile = open("filename.txt", "wb")
# write to file
newFile.write(myBytearray)
```