# Python: how to write a 32-bit float number into a file?

Tags: python

This code gives:
`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'float'`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    f32_number = float(1)
    with open("test.f32", "wb") as f:
        f.write(f32_number)
```

How do I write a float 32-bit number into a binary file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a float to bytearray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893206/converting-a-float-to-bytearray)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the number to `bytes` using [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html):

```
import struct

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f32_number = float(1)
    with open("test.f32", "wb") as f:
        b = struct.pack('f', f32_number)
        f.write(b)
```

If you want to share files between platforms, be wary of [endianness](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment). It will be better to explicitly use `>` or `<` in that case.